# Delphi's TFrames not keeping their size when reloading a project?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have a project with a lot of frames, and when I reload my project, they are resized to a width and height of 443x270, or thereabout.

I do reside the frames at runtime, but I wish they would remain as I create them at design time.

I use the non-embedded, classic undocked view. Anyone has any idea on how to have the frames keep their size between programming sessions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the secret here is to not set your frame alignment of your source frame at design time.  It should be alNone.  Once you PLACE the frame then adjust it to alClient (or do it in code if your adding fames dynamically)

Comment: I believe you are absolutely right, because all the frames that were resized had an alignment set! Upon changing them to alNone and changing the alignment on the added frame instead of its ancestor, all was back to normal.

Many thanks!

Comment: You ought to report this to QC as a bug.